# How to compute $E[X]$ in this case?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

Given this mass density function: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{{e}^{-\left(y + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}, \ x \gt \ 0, \ y \gt \ 0  $$
I need to compute $Cov[X,Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$. I know that $Y$ is an $Exp(1)$, therefore $E[Y] = 1$. But I can't seem to find a way to compute $E[X]$.

Comment: Are you sure that's the mass function and not the distribution? Because the probability mass function needs to satisfy:$$\int f_{X,Y}(x,y) \operatorname{d} x \operatorname{d}y = 1,$$ and I think you'll find that when you try that integral it diverges.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = 1$$ ?? Because it does converge. Take $dx$ first and then $dy$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{e}^{-\left(x + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}dx = e^{-y} $$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{-y}dy = 1 $$

I computed these results via Wolfram Mathematica.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{{e}^{-\left(x + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}dx = \frac1{y+1}$.
I computed this result [via Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-(x%2Bx%2Fy)%5D%2Fy,%7Bx,0,Infinity%7D%5D).

Comment: This is wrong. The first integral is $\frac{1}{y + 1}$. This is just an opinion, but it's not a good idea to use a computer for integrals that are easily done by hand.

Comment: Check how you typed it into Mathematica. I get the same asnwer as others when I type in: `Integrate[Exp[-(x + x/y)]/y, {x, 0, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Also, in situations like this when the integral limits are omitted, it is assumed by convention that the integration is carried out over the entire domain of the variables.

Comment: I probably typed something wrong, just went back and you guys are right. And now the integral does not converge. And I'm kinda on the clock, so I don't really have the time to go back and check everything so I just throw it in the software.

Comment: Is it possible to use the Tonelli's Theorem in this problem?

Comment: I typed the wrong mass function, how great is that????

Comment: Bottom line, either the PMF is copied incorrectly, or the domain of the PMF is wrong. For example, if $y$ is limited to $(0,\operatorname{e}-1]$ then it is a proper and normalized PMF.

Comment: The right one is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{{e}^{-\left(y + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}, \ x \gt \ 0, \ y \gt \ 0  $$ and it does converge.

Comment: Okay, so I tried using Tonelli's theorem:

$$E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\left(y + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}dxdy = \int_{{[0,\infty)}^2}\frac{xe^{-\left(y + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}dxdy \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-\left(y + \frac{x}{y}\right)}}{y}dxdy= \int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y}dy = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

The expectation values are given by the moments of the probability mass function. Explicitly: $$\operatorname{E}[X^nY^m] = \int f_{X,Y}(x, y) x^n y^m \operatorname{d}x \operatorname{d}y.$$
In this case you may have an easier time if you compute the integrals in a particular order. Specifically, do the $x$ integral before the $y$.

Comment: And you can compute this integral for general $m,n$ if you know $$\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t} \,dt = \Gamma(n+1) = n!$$